# Java.lang.classcastexception trying to convert blob to bufferedImage variable

Tags: java

I am trying to select the image from a table which is retrieved from the database and then displays it as an icon on a label.
 i found it difficult to convert object returned by `getValueAt()` method to bufferedImage object..

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   try
   {
       pr=con.prepareStatement("SELECT `sender id`, `image`, `status` FROM `transfer` WHERE `receiver_id`=?");
       pr.setString(1,jTextField3.getText());
       rs=pr.executeQuery();
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
   }
}                                        

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
try
{
int index=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
TableModel model=jTable1.getModel();
**BufferedImage ima=(BufferedImage) model.getValueAt(index,1);**
JLabel l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ima));
imagePane.getViewport().add(l);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert blob to InputStream, and then to BufferedImage:

```
TableModel model=jTable1.getModel();
Blob myBlob = model.getValueAt(index, 1);
InputStream myIS = myBlob.getBinaryStream();
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(myIS);
```

Comment: i tried this before. As getValueAt() method returns object compiler force me to do casting(object to Blob). But then i get classCastException

Comment: But do you get Class cast exception when casting Object to Blob, or Blob to BufferedImage as the title says? Could you paste all of your code to try it out?

Comment: my images are stored in the database. I retrieve image from database and display them in JTbale. I want that when a user clicks on a row selected image should be displayed on the screen. I am trying to store selected image in BufferedImage for further processing where I am getting classCast Exception.